# facing error while Creating the channel Hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

i need help i am using HLF 2.0 and developing fabric network which contain 2-ORG(1 peer each) ,raft(1 orderer) ,ca for both ORG (but till now there is only 1 ca-ORG1),2 couchdb container ,and last cli container container.

The network is up successfully ,but when i run the cmd to  create channel(having name "onechannel") it show error. you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7hKE.png).Even All the crypto materials and certificates exists .And the code/script which i am running for creating channel is mentioned below

some Environmental variables & cmd for creating channel

```
enter code echo "###########  Creating Channel One as Org1 Peer  ##################"
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}
export CHANNEL_NAME=onecannel
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cryptoconfig/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
export PEER0_OGR1_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-/config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export PEER0_OGR2_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/cryptoconfig/peerOrganizations /org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_OGR1_CA" cli peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_ONE_NAME.block --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

NoW The docker compose is here which i am using : the docker compose file is runing up successfully . i thing the error may be in PATH OR RELATIVE_PATH

```
version: "2"

networks:
   test:

services:
ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
        - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=org1.example.com
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/ca-server-config/priv_sk 
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/priv_sk
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
        - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
        - test

orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        # TLS ENABLAE
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
        - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
        - 7050:7050
    networks:
        - test
  



        
couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
        - COUCHDB_USER=
        - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
        # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
        # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
        - "5984:5984"
    networks:
        - test
  
peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
        - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
        - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
        - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
        - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:8051
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
        - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
        - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
        - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
        - 7051:7051
    depends_on:
        - couchdb0
    networks:
        - test





couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
        - COUCHDB_USER=
        - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
        # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
        # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
        - "6984:5984"
    networks:
        - test
  

peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
        - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
        - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
        - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
        - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
        #- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:10051
        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
        # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
        # bridge network as the peers
        # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
        - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
        #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
        - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
        # Allow more time for chaincode container to build on install.
        - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
        - 8051:8051
    depends_on:
        - couchdb1
    networks:
        - test


    

cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
        - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
        #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
        - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
        - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
        - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
        - orderer.example.com
        - peer0.org1.example.com
        - peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
        - test





         code here
```

i hope you expert can help me to get out of this problem and provide the good suggestions and solution . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides between the crypto-material folder and CLI service definition
In your docker-compose file under cli there is a volume between a folder named **crypto-config** and the repository **/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/**
This crypto-config folder is supposed to have your network identities nested as follow :

- /crypto-config

  - /peerOrganizations

    - other cryptomaterials
    - /users

      - /Admin@org1.example.com

        - /msp
        - /tls

The content of this folder is supposed to be generated by **cryptogen** tool and **crypto-config.yaml** file and folder will be named according to how you write it

And this content should be available to CLI environment variable like

```yaml
- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
```

You should verify that your crypto-material are generated inside the crypto-config file and their paths are consistent with what is defined under CLI volumes and the environment variables